# Label is slightly lower than text input

Tags: html, css

I have a label to the left of a text input but it looks like the text is just slightly below the bottom of the input. Here is my relevant HTML:

```
  <div id="nickbox">
    <label for="nickname" id="nicklabel">Nickname:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nickname" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" role="textbox"
        aria-label="Enter your nickname." data-lpignore="true" autofocus />
    <input type="button" id="nicknameconfirm" value="Set" />
  </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#nickbox {
  border: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff00;
  align-self:center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#nickname {
  background-color: #44475a;
  border: none;
  height: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  outline: none;
}
```

[This is what the results look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvkRV.png) What can I do to change this? I assume I need to add some CSS to #nicklabel. Thanks.

Comment: When I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8srcmnot/7/), the result looks perfectly fine. What browser(s) and/or system(s) are you testing with? Is there any other CSS present (e.g. from included libraries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `vertical-align: middle;` into `#nickname`

```
#nickname {
  background-color: #44475a;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  height: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  outline: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xqgb0mu/

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#nickbox {
  display: flex; /* Change display on parent */
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#nickname {
  background-color: #44475a;
  border: none;
  height: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  outline: none;
  align-self: center; /* Apply to child */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position: sticky; Like here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xpry1sn/)

```
#nicklabel{
    top: 13px;
    position: sticky;
}
```